# C programming: Finding max in a file string

Tags: c, string, file

I have this assignment that I can't figure out.

We have a file in the following format:

```
5
4 
100 500 250 300
1
700
3
300 150 175
2
920 680
8
20 10 15 25 50 30 19 23
```

On the first line we have the total number of auctions.

Afterwards, each two rows represent an auction.

On the first row there is the number of bids. On the following row there are the actual bids.

For example the number **4** describes an auction with 4 bids (100,500,250,300).

My task is to determine the highest bid for each auction. This is what I've got so far. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    FILE * ifp;
    char filename[100];

    printf("File name\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);

    ifp = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
        printf("Error, File could not be opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int i, num_auctions, auction, j, bid, max;

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num_auctions);

    for(i=0; i<num_auctions; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &auction);
        if (bid > max)
            max = bid;
            for(j=0; j<auction; j++){
                fscanf(ifp, "%d", &bid);
                printf("%d\n", bid);

            }
            printf("%d\n", max);
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post that image as text. There is no good reason to make us to click this link.

Comment: What is the value of `bid` the first time `if (bid > max)` is executed?

Comment: And please state what the current behaviour of your program is and why you can't figure it out.

Comment: One little addition, because you need to find the highes value for each, you should clear the `max` after the inner loop is finished. Print the max then clear it.

Comment: May I recommend that you find the compiler option that tells you when variables are used without being initialised? (Or alternatively, don't ignore the warnings that you are using uninitialised variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the problems in your code.

1. `bid` and `max` are used unintialised. Fix is to set them to 0 when they are declared.
2. The `if (bid > max)` check is in the wrong spot. It's only checking the last bid of each auction. The fix is to move that check into the inner `for` loop after the `fscanf`.
3. `max` needs to be cleared after each auction. The fix is to set `max` to 0 at the top of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to get the highest of each. I forgot to add to the original post that I also need the totals of those highest bids. I'm gonna edit the post to add that.

Comment: @Gary Please don't. That's a seperate issue.  We don't want questions to keep moving on to different problems. Try to do it yourself first. Post a new question if you get stuck including the exact summation code you tried.

Comment: Ok, sorry I never posted on here before, not sure how it's done. I have been trying total += max but i'll keep trying different things to see if I can get it. If not i'll write a new question.